# Order of $z\in Z(W)\backslash \{\rm{id}\}$ for $W$ the Weyl group.

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $z\in Z(W)\backslash \{\rm{id}\}$ for $W$ the Weyl group of a root system. I would like to show that it has order 2. Here is my attempted solution:

Since $z\in \rm{GL}(E)$ and leaves $\Phi$ invariant, by a certain result and the fact that $z$ is in the center of $W$, we have that $z\sigma_{\alpha}z^{-1} = \sigma_{z(\alpha)} = \sigma_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$. Then
                \begin{align}
     z\sigma_{\alpha}z^{-1}(\alpha) &= \sigma_{\alpha}(\alpha) = -\alpha \nonumber\\
     &= \sigma_{z(\alpha)}(\alpha) = \alpha -<\alpha,z(\alpha)> z(\alpha) \nonumber
    \end{align}
                and therefore $2\alpha = <\alpha,z(\alpha)> z(\alpha)$. Since this holds for all $\alpha \in \Phi$ and $<\alpha,z(\alpha)> \in \mathbb{Z}$, it must be that $z(\alpha) = \pm \alpha$. It was assumed that $z\neq \rm{id}$, therefore $z(\alpha) = -\alpha$ and thus has order 2.

It seems I have shown that this particular $z=-\rm{id}$, but the next problem I'm working on asks me to prove that $z=-\rm{id}$ when $\Phi$ is irreducible. Have I made some illogical conclusions?

Comment: Where did you get the equality $\sigma_{z(\alpha)} = \sigma_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $z$ is in the center, thus commutes in particular with the reflection $\sigma_{\alpha}$. The $z\sigma_{\alpha}z^{-1}=\sigma_{z(\alpha)}$ is the lemma on page 43 in Humphreys book.

Comment: Ahh, right. The issue is that $z(\alpha) = \alpha$ does not imply that $z = id$, unless this was for all $\alpha$. But it can happen that it is $1$ for some of them and $-1$ for others.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right, but $z$ was chosen specifically so that $z\neq id$. Is it then not the case that it is $-id$? Or, equally important, have I assumed $\Phi$ to be irreducible at some step without knowing perhaps?

Comment: Neither. You have assumed that it is impossible to have $z(\alpha) = \alpha$ for some simple root without $z$ being the identity. But this is certainly possible. To see an example, just take $A_1\times A_1$.

Comment: Right! I finally saw it. But I have at least shown that it has order 2, correct?

And if so, do you have some advice on how to tailor it to show $z=-id$ when $\Phi$ is irreducible?

Comment: Correct. I have not thought much about the connected case (apart from verifying it in my head using that I already know the Weyl groups of those). But my guess would be that if you assume it is $1$ on one of the simple roots, then it must also be $1$ on any simple root connected to it, by considering the sum of them (which is then itself a root).

Comment: What do you mean by connected exactly? I'm fairly new to Lie Algebras and root systems.

Comment: Two simple roots are connected if their inner product is non-zero (which is the same as their sum being a root). The root system is irreducible if you can "connect" any two simple roots via a sequence of simple roots where each one is connected to the previous one.

Comment: Ok, I understand the part about how you can find a sequence of simple roots from one simple root to another so that each is connected to the previous one. But, I don't really see how I can form a root from the two "end-simple roots". Or is that not possible? You wrote connect in quotation marks, so maybe not? Sorry if I'm being slow, it's very late here and I need to get this done.

Never mind. If I apply the argument that if $z$ is 1 on one simple root, then it is $1$ on the next in the sequence. And then I carry on until I reach my end root, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wrote "connect" because indeed the simple roots in the ends will not be connected in the sense that their inner product is non-zero (to see this just take type $A_3$ with the roots corresponding to the ends).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to flag this as answered: My last argument that $z(\alpha) = -\alpha$ is incorrect, since all we know is it can't be the case that $z(\alpha) = \alpha$ for all $\alpha$, but certainly some of them. The element $z$ has, however, order 2.